# File input validation using React Hook Form and Yup

Tags: reactjs, validation, yup, react-hook-form

I try to make file input validation using React Hook Form and Yup. I wrote the code below but when I am testing the size of file it shows me here `console.log(value[0].size);` that the value is undefined even if I selected a file in file input. What is wrong with it?

I am using `FormProvider` and `useFormContext`.

In my Parent.js I have this code:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const addingProcess = () => {
    //..
  };

  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    photo: Yup.mixed()
      .required("You need to provide a file")
      .test("fileSize", "File Size is too large", (value) => {
        console.log(value[0].size);
        return value[0].size <= 5242880;
      })
      .test("fileType", "Unsupported File Format", (value) =>
        ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/jpg"].includes(value.type)
      ),
  });

  const methods = useForm({
    mode: "onSubmit",
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
  });

  const { handleSubmit } = methods;

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(addingProcess)}>
            <Photos />
        </Form>
      </FormProvider>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

In my Photos.js I have:

```
const Photos = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
    <PhotoHolder/>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default Photos;
```

In my PhotoHolder.js file I have this (yes, I need to have the onChange like this):

```
const PhotoHolder = () => {
  const { register } = useFormContext();
  const validator = register("photo");

  return (
    <Input
    name="photo"
    type="file"
    multiple
    onChange={(e) => {
        validator.onChange(e);
    }}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: A little tip for anyone using this as a reference, I used the Yup test cases from this question as reference but they cased an error where the validation scheme would pass all fields, not only the file input, if the form was submitted without any file. This is because the length of the `value` parameter in the test case is `0` in this case so the `value[0]` causes an error. This can be fixed by adding a `?` after all instances of `value[0]` to handle this case

Comment: Hey, did you solve your issue and how? I have the same issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71826821/react-hook-form-reusable-controlled-file-input-component-value-handling-issue. If you know how to fix this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the function **useControl** with render like this:

```
<Controller
    control={control}
    name="photo"
    render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value, ref } }) => (
      <Photos
        onBlur={onBlur}
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        {...field}
      />
    )}
  />
```

By this method we can validate custom input, the key concept here is we have to pass control object and and and field into custom input component.

For more information you can visit this documentation https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller