# Single input separated by gaps React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hook-form

Is it possible to make an input file as below as one input file, not six separate inputs? This should work so that only when you click on the gray box, the file explorer opens. Regardless of which field we click, the same file input should open. The problem is that I don't want an explorer window to open when I click on the white gaps between the gray boxes. I must have it done like this because if I do six separate fields, I won't be able to validate it in react hook form.

Or is it possible to combine few inputs into one? I mean how to combine this three inputs below that they will share the same memory, regardless on which I click and to which I add some files?

```
<input type="file" />
<input type="file" />
<input type="file" />
```

Here You can find rest of my question and code:
[File input validation using React Hook Form and Yup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69104718/file-input-validation-using-react-hook-form-and-yup)

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the corresponding code for this page so we can see what might be going wrong?

Comment: I don't even know how to write such component that I described so I just ask how can I do this?

Comment: There is a way to have an input and select multiple files at once. It's an array of files